# 2-Dimensional ArrayList Error:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        arrayLists.get(0).add(100);
        arrayLists.get(0).add(50);
        arrayLists.get(1).add(67);
        System.out.println(arrayLists.get(0).get(0));
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I didnt understand the problem.

Comment: `arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());` The exception tell you you tried to get an item in the list at index 0 but the list have a size of 0 (empty). a list of list (`List<List>`) is just an empty `List` waiting for `List` instance to be added in;:

Comment: Since this is correctly answered, the duplicate can give you a complet explanation about the exception itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `List` of `List` but you never create instance of inner `List` so there is nothing to take, you have to :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
arrayLists.get(0).add(100);
arrayLists.get(0).add(50);

arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
arrayLists.get(1).add(67);

System.out.println(arrayLists.get(0).get(0));   // 100
System.out.println(arrayLists.get(0).get(1));   //  50
System.out.println(arrayLists.get(1).get(0));   //  67
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `ArrayList` inside the `ArrayList`. Change your code to

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Both above solutions gives you an idea about your problem, In case You you want to add multiple ArrayList in one shot, you can use [`ArrayList::addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) like this :

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
arrayLists.addAll(Arrays.asList(
        Lists.newArrayList(100, 50),
        Lists.newArrayList(67)
));
```

Or in one shot :

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        Lists.newArrayList(100, 50),
        Lists.newArrayList(67)
));
```

---

The [`List.newArrayList(..)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList()) is from Guava.

Comment: `Lists.newArrayList` is from Guava by the way. Don't know why it was never included... quite nice to have.

Comment: This is correct @AxelH It is helpful maybe in the next version of Java we can see it :)